# Code Geass R2 episode 7,there is a song playing at 6:40

Tags: music, code-geass

In Code Geass season 2 episode 7, there is a song playing at 6:40.This is about the time when Lelouch breaks his phone and throws it away when Kallen calls him. I can't find the song in the OST and I'm pretty sure it has been featured elsewhere in the series as well.

EDIT: I also noticed it play in episode 8 at 12:27.Corrected season number.

Comment: Are you talking about season 1 (R1) or season 2 (R2), either way I'm not hearing a song at any of those points, could you link me to the video you heard it on?

Comment: season 2(R2), episode 7 just after lelouch breaks his phone, we hear this play in the background.This piece plays in multiple different places and i just happened to remember these two points.

Comment: What I found was it is not released as an OST yet. But it is probably a piano version of Yuukyou Seishunka by Ali Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [a playlist on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb4mticUuCmQSnQpXJDttkzbhOxAdnGWf) that includes all the tracks excluded from the OST.

The track you are looking for is "Path of Decisions". It is [the 30th video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yi88NrNYA1I&index=30&list=PLb4mticUuCmQSnQpXJDttkzbhOxAdnGWf&) in the playlist I mentioned before.